# Difference between 'echo' when using Ash vs. Bash

Tags: bash, echo

On one system, I am able to use a sysfs driver by calling

```
echo 1 > enable
```

but on another system with the same kernel, but a different filesystem, doing the same command fails.

The failure that occurs is

```
ash: write error: Invalid argument
```

whereas on the system where it DOES work, I notice that the shell used is Bash.

Would there be a difference between calling a program like echo using Ash vs Bash?

Comment: It should work the same for `echo 1 > enable`. It's the *same* file system because both are sysfs. And each shell is writing `1\n` to the `enable` file. Try it on another sysfs file that doesn't matter.

Comment: Is the trailing single quote intentional or a typo?

Comment: Typo. I'll fix.